# 複数のファイルから必要なキーを取り出してCSVファイルに書き出す処理時間を短縮するには

Tags: c#

複数のファイルの中からそれぞれ必要なキーを抽出して1つのcsvファイルにリストを書き出す処理をしています。

- 元のデータは1ファイル辺り約800行(40kB程度)が約18万件、トータルで約8GBほど
- 必要なデータを取り出した結果ファイルは10MB程度になる

動作の確認等は出来たのですが処理に時間がかかりすぎていて、先輩がPerlで作ったものだと約240秒ほどで処理が完了するのですが、私がC#で書いたコードだと処理が完了するのに約1時間も時間がかかってしまいます。まだC#を勉強し始めて間もないですがコードの中に無駄な処理があるのか変なループがあるのかが分かりません。

この処理を最短に時間短縮出来るような書き方があれば教えていただきたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class DatRowValues
    {
        public string ProcessData { get; set; }
        public string KeyValue { get; set; }
        public string IntValue { get; set; }
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    class NewDatRowValues
    {
        public string EqpId { get; set; }
        public string LotId { get; set; }
        public string WaferId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SDate { get; set; }
        public string  TempBRINECoolant { get; set; }
    }
    class NewDatRowValuesMapper : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<NewDatRowValues>
    {
        public NewDatRowValuesMapper()
        {
            Map(x => x.EqpId).Index(0);
            Map(x => x.LotId).Index(1);
            Map(x => x.WaferId).Index(2);
            Map(x => x.SDate).Index(3).TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Map(x => x.TempBRINECoolant).Index(4);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // 書き出し用の入れ物を用意
            var writeDatList = new List<NewDatRowValues>();

            // 読み込み
            foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\20190403", "*.dat"))
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis")))
                using (var inputDat = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sr))
                {
                    inputDat.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

                    // 必要なキーとなる行のみ抽出
                    var dat = inputDat.GetRecords<DatRowValues>();
                    var targetRows = dat.Where(r =>
                    r.KeyValue == "EQP_ID" ||
                    r.KeyValue == "LOT_ID" ||
                    r.KeyValue == "WAFER_ID" ||
                    r.KeyValue == "S_DATE" ||
                    r.KeyValue == "TempBRINECoolant");

                    // それぞれの値を格納
                    var newRow = new NewDatRowValues();
                    foreach (var row in targetRows)
                    {
                        if (row.KeyValue == "EQP_ID")
                        {
                            newRow.EqpId = row.StringValue;
                        }
                        if (row.KeyValue == "LOT_ID")
                        {
                            newRow.LotId = row.StringValue;
                        }
                        if (row.KeyValue == "WAFER_ID")
                        {
                            newRow.WaferId = row.StringValue;
                        }
                        if (row.KeyValue == "S_DATE")
                        {
                            newRow.SDate = DateTime.Parse(row.StringValue);
                        }
                        if (row.KeyValue == "TempBRINECoolant")
                        {
                            newRow.TempBRINECoolant = row.StringValue;
                        }
                    }
                    writeDatList.Add(newRow);
                }
            // 書き出し
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\テスト\list1.csv"))
            using (var outputDat = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                var writingList = writeDatList.GroupBy(r => r.EqpId.Substring(0, 4))
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .SelectMany(g => g)
                    .ToList();
                outputDat.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                outputDat.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<NewDatRowValuesMapper>();
                outputDat.WriteRecords(writingList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**元データ (1ファイルの中身)**

```
\\,AACZ12501_93G25701901,93G257019-18,TSN.PR,TSN-LCT,AACZ12501,2019/04/04 00:00:31,実処理データ
ProcessData,LOT_ID,3,AP0077130.00C,
ProcessData,LOT_ID_SUB,3,AP0077130.00,
ProcessData,LOT_NO,3,AP0077130,
ProcessData,WAFER_ID,3,AP0077130.18,
ProcessData,WAFER_NO,1,18,
ProcessData,PRODSPEC_ID,3,T6BD60001-00001.00,
ProcessData,PRODGRP_ID,3,T6BD6,
ProcessData,PRODGRP_BIND,3,T6BD6,
ProcessData,MAIN_MAINPD_ID,3,A5L501PC.00,
ProcessData,MAINPD_ID,3,A5L501PC.00,
ProcessData,FLOW_TYPE,3,Main,
ProcessData,FLOW_TYPE_NO,1,1,
ProcessData,D_SEQNO,1,89,
ProcessData,OP_NO,3,TSN CT Coat.MA1,
ProcessData,OP_NO_NAME,3,本処理,
ProcessData,PD_IDENT,3,KTSNIMA1.00,
ProcessData,PD_IDENT_NAME,3,COAT,
ProcessData,EQP_GROUP_CODE,3,PCOT,
ProcessData,EQP_GROUP_NAME,3,RESIST C/T,
ProcessData,EQP_GROUP_BIND,3,PCOT,
ProcessData,EQP_ID,3,PCOT003,
ProcessData,PH_RECIPE_ID,3,084,
ProcessData,RCP_NAME_SPACE,3,PEPPR,
ProcessData,LC_RECIPE_ID,3,V146G-420-10+AQ7.00,
ProcessData,RECIPE_ID,3,PEPPR.084,
ProcessData,S_DATE,4,2019/04/03 23:48:08,
ProcessData,E_DATE,4,2019/04/04 00:00:31,
ProcessData,CAST_ID,3,PA0-01239,
ProcessData,SLOT_NO,1,18,
ProcessData,DEPT_CODE,3,DEPT,
ProcessData,HIST_S_DATE_1,4,2019/04/03 23:48:08,
ProcessData,HIST_E_DATE_1,4,2019/04/04 00:00:31,
ProcessData,Clock_C,3,2019040400003155,
ProcessData,EventName_C,3,STS At Destination,
ProcessData,SubstID_C,3,AP0077130.18,
ProcessData,ProcessJobID_C,3,AP0077130.01,
ProcessData,PPID_C,3,RegFlowRcpClass/084,
ProcessData,ControlJobID_C,3,PCOT003-20190403-0053,
ProcessData,WaferSequenceNo_C,3,18,
ProcessData,SubstProcState_C,3,2,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Cup temp.,2,23.07,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Cup humidity,2,45.26,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Resist temp.,2,23.00,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Motor flange temp.,2,23.00,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Solvent bath flow,2,0.0,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Back rinse flow 1,2,0.0,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Back rinse flow 2,2,0.0,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Drain case Rinse,2,0.0,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Back rinse1+2 flow,2,64.8,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Side rinse flow,2,4.8,
ProcessData,_TCT-02_Cup wind velocity,2,0.38,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Cup temp.,2,23.08,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Cup humidity,2,45.31,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Resist temp.,2,23.02,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Motor flange temp.,2,23.00,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Solvent bath flow,2,0.0,
ProcessData,_COT-02_RRC Nozzle flow,2,2.5,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Drain case Rinse,2,0.0,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Back rinse1+2 flow,2,81.7,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Side rinse flow,2,21.4,
ProcessData,_COT-02_Cup wind velocity,2,0.40,
ProcessData,_ADH-02_Plate temp.,2,100.03,
ProcessData,_ADH-02_HMDS flow,2,5553.9,
ProcessData,_CPL-03_Plate temp.,2,24.00,
ProcessData,_CPL-05_Plate temp.,2,23.00,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp.,2,109.99,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp. 1,2,109.98,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp. 2,2,110.02,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp. 3,2,110.02,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp. 4,2,110.01,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp. 5,2,109.99,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp. 6,2,109.98,
ProcessData,_PHP-03_Plate temp. 7,2,109.99,
ProcessData,SlotStatus_C,3,3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0,
ProcessData,PortID_C,3,1,
ProcessData,LotID_C,3,AP0077130.00C,
ProcessData,SubstDestination_C,3,PA0-01239.18,
ProcessData,SubstLocID1_C,3,PA0-01239.18,
ProcessData,Timein1_C,3,2019040323394290,
ProcessData,Timeout1_C,3,2019040323480827,
ProcessData,SubstLocID2_C,3,[2-05]TRS01,
ProcessData,Timein2_C,3,2019040323481433,
ProcessData,Timeout2_C,3,2019040323482607,
ProcessData,SubstLocID3_C,3,[2-15]ADH02,
ProcessData,Timein3_C,3,2019040323482957,
ProcessData,Timeout3_C,3,2019040323493000,
ProcessData,SubstLocID4_C,3,[2-21]CPL05,
ProcessData,Timein4_C,3,2019040323493567,
ProcessData,Timeout4_C,3,2019040323503524,
ProcessData,SubstLocID5_C,3,[2-02]COT02,
ProcessData,Timein5_C,3,2019040323504071,
ProcessData,Timeout5_C,3,2019040323514101,
ProcessData,SubstLocID6_C,3,[2-24]PHP03,
ProcessData,Timein6_C,3,2019040323514584,
ProcessData,Timeout6_C,3,2019040323533013,
ProcessData,SubstLocID7_C,3,[2-17]CPL03,
ProcessData,Timein7_C,3,2019040323533561,
ProcessData,Timeout7_C,3,2019040323563468,
ProcessData,SubstLocID8_C,3,[2-04]TCT02,
ProcessData,Timein8_C,3,2019040323564008,
ProcessData,Timeout8_C,3,2019040400001710,
ProcessData,SubstLocID9_C,3,[2-06]TRS02,
ProcessData,Timein9_C,3,2019040400002061,
ProcessData,Timeout9_C,3,2019040400002521,
ProcessData,SubstMtrlStatus_C,3,0,
ProcessData,SubstSource_C,3,PA0-01239.18,
ProcessData,SubstState_C,3,2,
ProcessData,SubstType_C,3,0,
ProcessData,SubstUsage_C,3,0,
ProcessData,CLOCK1_C,3,2019040323480827,
ProcessData,CLOCK2_C,3,2019040400003153,
```

出力後のcsvファイルの中身（一部）は以下のようになっています。

```
PCOT003 AP0077130.00C   AP0077130.18    2019/4/3 23:48
PCOT004 AP0077164.00C   AP0077164.16    2019/4/3 23:49
PCOT004 AP0077164.00C   AP0077164.17    2019/4/3 23:50
PCOT008 AP0076967.00C   AP0076967.01    2019/4/3 23:56
PCOT001 SP0008774.00C   SP0008774.02    2019/4/3 23:50
PCOT002 SP0009131.00C   SP0009131.03    2019/4/3 23:53
PCOT002 SP0009131.00C   SP0009131.02    2019/4/3 23:53
PCOT001 SP0008774.00C   SP0008774.03    2019/4/3 23:50
PCOT008 AP0076967.00C   AP0076967.03    2019/4/3 23:56
PCOT008 AP0076967.00C   AP0076967.02    2019/4/3 23:56
PCOT004 AP0077164.00C   AP0077164.18    2019/4/3 23:50
PCOT002 SP0009131.00C   SP0009131.04    2019/4/3 23:54
PCOT008 AP0076967.00C   AP0076967.04    2019/4/3 23:56
PCOT004 AP0077164.00C   AP0077164.20    2019/4/3 23:52
PCOT004 AP0077164.00C   AP0077164.19    2019/4/3 23:51
PCOT003 AP0077130.00C   AP0077130.19    2019/4/3 23:48
PCOT002 SP0009131.00C   SP0009131.06    2019/4/3 23:55
PCOT002 SP0009131.00C   SP0009131.05    2019/4/3 23:54
PCOT001 SP0008774.00C   SP0008774.05    2019/4/3 23:50
```

1ファイルから1行出力しています。

以下Perlのコードを頂きましたので参考程度に載せておきます。

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $dirname = 'C:\Users\0020316094\Desktop\Perl\development_1\data';
my @list;
my $count = 0;
my @Lot;
my @Waf;
my @Eqp;
my @Date;
my @lot_id;
my @waf_id;
my @eqp_id;
my @date_id;

my $start_time = time;

opendir(DIR, $dirname) or die "$dirname: $!";
while (my $dir = readdir (DIR)) {
    next if $dir eq '.' || $dir eq '..' || $dir eq 'test.txt' || $dir eq 'file_get.pl';     #.を除外する処理
    push @list, $dir;   #配列に入れる
}
closedir (DIR);


foreach (@list) {

#   open(FILE, "<", "C:\Users\0020316094\Desktop\Perl\development_1\data\$list[$count]") or die "$!";
    open(FILE, "<", "$list[$count]") or die "$!";    #修正前

    while (my $line = <FILE>) {

        @lot_id = split(/,/, $line) if $line =~ /,LOT_ID,/;
        $Lot[$count] = $lot_id[3];
        @waf_id = split(/,/, $line) if $line =~ /,WAFER_ID,/;
        $Waf[$count] = $waf_id[3];
        @eqp_id = split(/,/, $line) if $line =~ /,EQP_ID,/;
        $Eqp[$count] = $eqp_id[3];
        @date_id = split(/,/, $line) if $line =~ /,S_DATE,/;
        $Date[$count] = $date_id[3];
    }
    close (FILE);
$count++
}
my $count1 = 0;
open(TXT, ">>test.txt") or die "$!";
foreach (@Lot) {
    print TXT "$Lot[$count1],$Waf[$count1],$Eqp[$count1],$Date[$count1]\n";
    $count1++
}
close (TXT);
```

Comment: タイトルはなるべくシンプルに、「質問の要約」を記述するよう心掛けてみて下さい。細かい数字等は本文で説明した方がよいでしょう。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。初めてなもので勝手が分かっていませんでした。

Comment: 入力ファイル、出力ファイルのサンプルがあればと…コードが正しいのか判断できません。１入力ファイルが出力ファイル１行分であってますか？ 出力の`Index(1)`が被っているのも気になります。

Comment: 失礼しました。出力の部分で正しくはMap(x => x.TempBRINECoolant).Index(4);でした。出力の数を減らして時間を調べていて戻すのを忘れていました。

Comment: @ShinyaKojima 質問の際に書き誤ったのか、それともプログラム自体が間違っていたのか、どちらでしょうか？ 後者であれば修正により速度改善の有無も。

Comment: 見づらいかもしれませんが元データと出力後のデータを追加しました。質問の際に書き誤ったものです。失礼しました。

Comment: 先輩がPerlで書いたコードは、正規表現を上手に使って入力ファイルから必要な情報を取り出し、それを出力するようなものだったのではないかと想像します。　"とにかく全データを揃えて"ではなく"必要最低限のデータを揃えて"を心がけると、処理が早くできる事が多いです。

Comment: 18万のファイルを１つ１つ読み込んで探したら時間がかかるからまとめて読み込んでその中から必要なものだけを取り出すといわれましたが。Pearlのコードは読めないのですがそれにしても240秒で終わるのはとても速いと感じました。持ってるPCのスペックも同じなので、なぜそこまで差が開くのか・・・

Comment: 元のPerlのコードも参考情報として載せることは可能ですか？ / 細かい話ですがプログラミング言語の`Perl`は`a`が入らないのでお間違えないよう…(`Pearl`とは綴りが違う)

Comment: Perlのコードを送ってもらえるか確認してみます。　あ、綴り勘違いしていました・・・お恥ずかしい

Comment: ありがちなのは、それぞれのキーがある行番号が決まっていて、その行だけ抽出して処理しているとか。

Comment: すべての行を読み込みパースしてオブジェクト化しているのが遅い原因ではないでしょうか？ インスタンス作成はかなり高コストです。

Comment: 必要なデータに対して不要なデータが多いので、私なら前処理として`grep`なりで「必要なデータだけ」のログを(別ファイルに)抜き出してから集計をかける、ということをよくやります。

Comment: 元のPerlのコードを載せました。手順としては①配列を１行ずつ読み込んでLOT_ID、WAFER_ID、EQP_ID、S_DATEを読み込んで１８万回繰り返してテキストの書き込む列を決めて書き込むだけのようです

Answer (score 2):

読み込むファイルが18万件、で約8GBということなので、
その読み込みにどれほどの時間がかかっているのでしょうか？

全て読み込んで、それに対して何もせずに終了したら、どれくらいかかるのでしょう？
１、2分なのか、50分くらいなのか。これが長い時間かかるようなら、
ファイルのIOだけで時間をとられていることになるので、検索部分を
改良してもダメですね。

まず、どこに時間がかかっているのか、探してみないと
いけないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 見方がまだよく分かっていませんがプロセスメモリは常に１２MBで平行に動いています。CPU使用率も１５%辺りで落ち着いているみたいです。

Answer (score 0):

Perl相当の解析処理を書いてみました。

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp6 {
    class Output {
        public string LotId { get; set; }
        public string WaferId { get; set; }
        public string EqpId { get; set; }
        public string SDate { get; set; }
    }

    class Program {
        static Output Convert(string fileName) {
            var output = new Output();
            foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName, Encoding.Default)) {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, ",LOT_ID,"))
                    output.LotId = line.Split(',')[3];
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, ",WAFER_ID,"))
                    output.WaferId = line.Split(',')[3];
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, ",EQP_ID,"))
                    output.EqpId = line.Split(',')[3];
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, ",S_DATE,"))
                    output.SDate = line.Split(',')[3];
            }
            return output;
        }
        static IEnumerable<Output> Read() {
            return Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\20190403", "*.dat")
                // 次行のコメントを外すとマルチスレッド並列で処理するようになります。
                // .AsParallel()
                .Select(fileName => Convert(fileName));
        }
        static void Main() {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\テスト\list1.csv")) {
                foreach (var output in Read())
                    sw.WriteLine($"{output.LotId},{output.WaferId},{output.EqpId},{output.SDate}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

速くなるかわかりませんが、思いつく範囲でいじってみました。コメントはコードに対するものというよりは、回答の一部として書いています。

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp6 {
    // 不要なカラムは読み捨てるようにしました。
    class Input {
        [Index(1)]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [Index(3)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    class Output {
        public string EqpId { get; set; }
        public string LotId { get; set; }
        public string WaferId { get; set; }
        // 日付は解析しないようにしました。
        public string SDate { get; set; }
        public string TempBRINECoolant { get; set; }
    }

    class Program {
        static IEnumerable<Output> Read() {
            return Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\20190403", "*.dat")
                // 次行のコメントを外すとマルチスレッド並列で処理するようになります。
                // .AsParallel()
                .Select(fileName => {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Default))
                    using (var reader = new CsvReader(sr)) {
                        reader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                        var output = new Output();
                        // Whereでの事前フィルタリングは二度手間なだけなので削除しました。
                        foreach (var row in reader.GetRecords<Input>()) {
                            // else ifとなっていなかったので比較回数が増えていました。
                            // どうせなのでswitch文にしました。
                            switch (row.Key) {
                                case "EQP_ID":
                                    output.EqpId = row.Value;
                                    break;
                                case "LOT_ID":
                                    output.LotId = row.Value;
                                    break;
                                case "WAFER_ID":
                                    output.WaferId = row.Value;
                                    break;
                                case "S_DATE":
                                    output.SDate = row.Value;
                                    break;
                                case "TempBRINECoolant":
                                    output.TempBRINECoolant = row.Value;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        return output;
                    }
                });
        }

        static void Main() {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\テスト\list1.csv"))
            using (var writer = new CsvWriter(sw)) {
                writer.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                var rows = Read()
                    .GroupBy(r => r.EqpId.Substring(0, 4))
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .SelectMany(g => g);
                writer.WriteRecords(rows);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

どうでしょうか？

Comment: 揚げ足を取るつもりではないのですが               return output;
                    }
                });　←ここの部分がどうなっているのか分からないです
        }

        static void Main() {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\テスト\list1.csv"))

Comment: 実際に動かして確認したところ51分で処理が完了しました。質問に記していたコードだと54分だったので3分ほど時間が短縮されました。

Comment: Perl相当の解析処理ありがとうございます。現在動かしてみました。結果は２８分で処理が完了しました。

Answer (score 0):

まず、どこに処理負荷がかかっているかを探すのがよいかと思われます。
今回の場合、ファイル読み込み自体が重いのか、それともCsvHelperが重いのか、が考えられます。

まずは `StreamReader` で開いて `ReadToEnd()` で読み捨てする実装だけで読み込み自体の負荷を計測します。これだけで処理が一時間近くかかるようであれば、.NETファイルアクセスの仕様の可能性があり、改善は難しいです。並列動作にしてどうなるかぐらいでしょうか。

先の検証で読み込み自体の負荷が問題でない場合、CsvHelperが重い可能性があります。比較的単純なCSVフォーマットのようですので、自前で文字列操作を実装したほうが速度は期待できます。

VisualStudioであれば、[診断ツール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)を活用することで関数単位の負荷が調べられるので、細かい調査にはこちらが使えるかもしれません。

Comment: かぶった… uemさんの言ってることと内容は同じです。

Answer (score 0):

ちなみに、`CsvReader`は含まれないけれど、いくつかの読み取り方の速度比較の記事が以下にあります。
[【C#】ファイル読み取り速度比較](https://orizuru.io/blog/csharp/file-reading/)

尻馬に乗る形ですが、@sayuri さんの Perl相当処理のstatic Output Convert()を以下のようにしてみたら、少し速いかも。(途中で break するので悪影響あるかもですが)

```
    private static readonly Encoding Enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis");

    static Output Convert(string fileName)
    {
        var output = new Output();
        int dataflags = 0;
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName, Enc))
        {
            string[] rec = line.Split(',');
            string value = rec[3];
            switch (rec[1])
            {
                case "EQP_ID":
                    output.EqpId = value;
                    dataflags |= 0x01;
                    break;
                case "LOT_ID":
                    output.LotId = value;
                    dataflags |= 0x02;
                    break;
                case "WAFER_ID":
                    output.WaferId = value;
                    dataflags |= 0x04;
                    break;
                case "S_DATE":
                    output.SDate = value.Substring(0, 16);
                    dataflags |= 0x08;
                    break;
            }
            if (dataflags == 0x0F)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: プログラミングも奥がかなり深いですね・・・・結果が同じでもコードの書き方は様々で、まさか読み取り速度にも違いがあるとは思いませんでした。C#初心者の為、いろんな情報が入ってきてすでにパンクしてますが整理して自分のものに出来たらと思います。ちなみにこちらのコードも引用させていただきました。プロセスメモリは13.8MBで安定していてCPU使用率は8~15%あたりです。結果は19分でした。また更に早く処理ができました。このdataflags |= 0×01;とか初めて見るものが書いてあるのですが、どういうことですか？

Comment: データが見つかったら、見つけたという状態をあらわす、それぞれのデータに対応するビットをONにしています。フラグを立てるとも言います。すべてのデータが揃ったら、もう検索ループを回す必要が無いので break するためです。

Comment: なるほど分からないなりに少し分かったような気がします。これ以上早く出来るのかは分からないですけど、あとはPCのスペックの問題なのでしょうか。それにしても1時間かかっていた処理がここまで時間短縮できるとは思いませんでした。ご協力いただいた皆様ありがとうございました。

Comment: まあ実際には Regex.IsMatch() を使わないようにしたのが一番影響していると思いますが。

Comment: @ShinyaKojima  「途中で break するので悪影響あるかもですが」の補足しておくと、キーが重複している場合に結果が異なります。Perlのコード及び私のコードは最後に出現した値を採用するのに対し、kunifさんのコードは最初に出現した値を採用します。１回しか出現しなければ結果は同じです。Perlがなんでそんなに速いのかまだちょっと謎です。Shift-JIS→Unicode変換かなぁ？